# Creating a new account in the network does not copy my existing Gravatar

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts, profile-picture, gravatar

I am learning LaTeX for fun and so I created a Stack Exchange account in [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) to upvote all the useful questions and answers over there.

I notice [my new account](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/220783/jokerdino) does not copy my Gravatar no matter what I do. It does not even have the option to let me choose to display Gravatar.

[image: No options to choose Gravatar]

I have tried the following to no benefits:

1. Saving the changes to all public communities from my main profile
2. Updating the profile info from my Stack Exchange profile

Comment: Yep, I get the same thing

Comment: Gravatars are still based on an obsolete Email field which can no longer be edited (no amount of copying changes will fix that, because the field is completely ignored). It looks like profiles are now being created with that field set to null, which makes it impossible to use Gravatar on new profiles. I'm not sure if that is a bug or an intentional change where this implication just wasn't considered, though.

Comment: @animuson even more reason to finally kill gravatars once and for all. And there were plenty of reasons to do that even before this

Comment: @MadScientist Oh I've wanted that to happen for a while, but for different selfish reasons. Intricacies behind Gravatar support are (last I heard) the only thing holding us back from just nuking that obsolete Email field from existence and updating everything to VerifiedEmail, and the continued existence of that field causes a bunch of weird account-related support problems that I wish I didn't have to deal with anymore. ::-)

Comment: @animuson According to [Transparent profile pictures should be rendered on a dark background in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399930/transparent-profile-pictures-should-be-rendered-on-a-dark-background-in-dark-mod) it's not possible to get a transparent image using "Upload picture". Which is why some of us are trying to do it using gravatar.com. What are the odds that it will come back as an option or alternatively that we'll be able to get the image to render with the transparent bits as transparent?